# Connect remote Interbase database freeze my app

Tags: delphi, networking, connection, c++builder, interbase

I have an application (C++Builder, Delphi) and I connect to remote Interbase database via IBX (TIBDatabase).

When try to connect to database using network and the IP address dosn't exists, so the application freeze for 20 seconds until the error message (Unable to complete network request to host "172.16.1.144:3050". Failed to establish a connection.) appears.

I try to connect to remote database using a new thread, also the app freeze.

How can try to connect without freeze the whole app ??

Thanks.

Comment: Can you at least show *how* you are trying to connect in  a thread?

Comment: Simply I add a new form to my app. and add TIBDatabase, and then show this form by a TThread object. and then when the form appears I try to connect the database with non exist IP address, the whole app freeze not just the form which is contains the IBDatabase component.

Comment: Forms are not thread safe; almost no visible element is. You should create and connect a separate TIBDatabase instance inside the TThread.Execute method and try to connect. If that succeeds, you can connect the instance on the form in the main thread.